# What is wrong with Zip Method in Linq using C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I had written the following code for comparing two tables,

```
var one = db.arabia_upod_item_availability_masters.Where(i => i.locationId == 30).OrderBy(i => i.itemNo).ToList();
var two = db.vw_get_arabia_upod_report_quantityOrderedPerItem_uhjs.OrderBy(i => i.Item_No).ToList();

if (one.Zip(two, (j, k) => j.itemNo == k.Item_No).Any(m => !m))
returnValue = true;
else
returnValue = false;
```

The problem is that the Zip method loops from first to last and then again first. For eg, if item no's are 1,2,3 it goes through 1,2,3 and then again 1 and it even returns false even though all the values match. What can be the problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) is a combining operator: it combines items from `One` with items from `Two` that are **in the same position** in the list. It seems to me you expect it to combine according to the filter.

Answer (score 0):

[Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) apply function to given elements of two sequence and producing the sequence of the results. you can use **Intersect** operator to return the intersection of two sequences

```
var q = one.Intersect(two)
```